# Control Vibration Frequency on Android

Tags: android, signals, frequency, vibration

I am trying to figure out a way to control the vibration frequency of the Android vibration motor. So far, I haven't found anything to allow me to do this. Is there any way to either figure out what the frequency of the vibration motor on the Android is, or even better control it?

Edit: The goal is not to make the android device vibrate, or to make it vibrate for an on off pattern. The goal is to make the Android device motor vibrate at a certain frequency. For example if it is an ERM motor, I want to make it rotate at a controlled RPM.

Comment: @0X0nosugar please see edit.

Comment: You're right, that's different. I'll delete the flag